# fault or error in this method

Tags: java, testing

I am revising for a software testing exam. One of the questions gives this method and asks to identify the fault as well as produce a test case (if one exists) which does not execute the fault.

Here is the code:

```
public static int oddOrPos(int[] x) {
  //Effects: if x==null throw NullPointerException
  // else return the number of elements in x that
  // are either odd or positive (or both)
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++)
  {
    if (x[i]%2 == 0 || x[i] > 0)
    { 
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

I have identified two problems. One being that i is initialised to 1 in the for loop so x[0] doesn't get tested. Also `x[i] % 2 == 0` should be `x[i] != 0`

Are these problems faults or errors? I ask this because the question makes it appear that there is only one fault.

Also, I assume that because the for loop will always be executed, there is no test case which will not execute the fault.

Comment: As for `x[i] % 2 == 0` see the other answers. You're right however, `i = 1` would return `0` for one-element arrays even if you change the condition to `x[i] % 2 == 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect *odd negative* values you'll have to look for `-1` and not for `0` as it's done right now.

For *odd positive* values it will be `1`. So basically you want **anything but** `0`.

The `%` operator is a remainder operator, not really a modulo operator, it returns a negative number if the first given number is negative:

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5 % 3;  // 2
        int b = 5 / 3;  // 1
        System.out.println("5%3 produces " + a +
                " (note that 5/3 produces " + b + ")");

        int c = 5 % (-3);  // 2
        int d = 5 / (-3);  // -1
        System.out.println("5%(-3) produces " + c +
                " (note that 5/(-3) produces " + d + ")");

        int e = (-5) % 3;  // -2
        int f = (-5) / 3;  // -1
        System.out.println("(-5)%3 produces " + e +
                " (note that (-5)/3 produces " + f + ")");

        int g = (-5) % (-3);  // -2
        int h = (-5) / (-3);  // 1
        System.out.println("(-5)%(-3) produces " + g +
                " (note that (-5)/(-3) produces " + h + ")");
    }
}
```

---

Another "small" fault is the way the condition is done. Instead of checking for **odd** or **positive**, looking for **positive** or **odd** will be slightly faster. It's only because it's easier to check if a number is positive or not than getting its remainder.

---

**Resources:**

- [15.17.3. Remainder Operator %](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3)

Answer (score 4):

Actually `x[i] % 2 == 0` should be `x[i] % 2 != 0` (if we want to detect **odd** values along with the positive ones. The existing code will detect **even** values instead).

The test case is just `{ -2 }` - this element is even and negative, so should not get counted, and the method will return `0` even though it is faulty. `{ 1 }` will also give `0`, which is wrong.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work quite like that with the remained operator, see my answer.

Comment: Correct, I forgot about negatives. Fixing.

Comment: but in your test case {2}, it it even, so shouldn't get counted but it is positive which should increase the count so the method would return 1 would it not?

Comment: My bad, I forgot about positives when writing the core of the answer. Hope it is fixed in full now.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that because the for loop always executes, there cannot be a test case which does NOT execute the fault?

Comment: Well, the loop **body** does not execute always. This avoids one fault. But the `i` initialization **is** executed always, and you cannot avoid it. If we are on the same page regarding the definition of _fault_.

Comment: my definition of a fault is: the collection of program source code statements that causes a failure.

Would any of these statements actually cause a failure?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10282/discussion-between-alexander-pavlov-and-sam)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are right in your assumption. The first position of the array should be tested, hence the `i[0]` you pointed out.

However, `x[i]%2 == 0` should instead be `x[i]%2 == 1` for an odd number.

Answer (score 0):

The major thing here is that your for loop is starting at 1, and it should start at 0. You will always miss the first element of the array. Also x[i]%2 == 0 returns true for even numbers, not odd. So change that to x[i]%2 != 0.

```
public class test{

public static void main(String[] args){
int[] x = {3, 5, -1, -14}

if( 3 == oddOrPos(x)){
    System.out.println("Working");
else
    System.out.println("Test Fail");

}
public static int oddOrPos(int[] x) {
  //Effects: if x==null throw NullPointerException
  // else return the number of elements in x that
 // are either odd or positive (or both)
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
 {
   if (x[i]%2 != 0 || x[i] > 0)
{ 
  count++;
}
 }
      return count;
}
}
```